# Method for checking if a string has been passed into a list

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I'm trying to create a method, in c#, which checks if a string has been passed into a list.

```
    private List<string> _identifiers;

    public Profile (string[] names)
    {
        _identifiers = new List<string>(names);
    }

    public bool Exists (string id)
    {
        if ((_identifiers [0] == "id1")&&(_identifiers [1] == "id2")) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Um, `_identifiers.Contains(id)`? (Note that your current code doesn't use `id` at all, and only checks in the first two values of `_identifiers`, which seems odd... Also note that any time you've got `if (...) return true; else return false;` you can just use `return ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq extension method:

```
return _identifiers.Contains(id);
```

Comment: More like `List<T>` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx